# ¿Cómo puedo convertir números con decimales a fracciones en Python?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Me gustaría imprimir valores numéricos con decimales en su forma de fracción:

```
0.5 a 1/2
0.75 a 3/4
4.5 a 9/2
```

¿Existe alguna librería nativa para realizar la conversión? ¿Cómo se realiza dicha conversión?

Comment: Parece simple, pero no es tan fácil... `0,5` son `5/10`. `0,75` son `75/100`, `4,5` son `45/10`, luego se simplifica de ambos números si coinciden los factores primos, por lo que será necesario un factorizador. Para los periódicos, `0,6667`, es más complejo, no se sabe si es `6667/10000` o `2/3`, en ese caso habrá que tomarlo como aproximado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase `Fraction` del módulo `fractions`:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction('0.5')
>>> b = Fraction('0.75')
>>> c = Fraction('4.5')
>>> print(a)
1/2
>>> print(b)
3/4
>>> print(c)
9/2
```

Si tienes los números guardados como reales, entonces puedes hacer la conversión explícita utilizando `str` y luego pasar eso la clase `Fraction`.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer una función recursiva que entrega valores para el numerador y denominador de la fracción, sin importar si está simplificado o no. Luego, simplificas o factorizas con el algoritmo de Euclides.

Te dejo el código para el algoritmo.

```
def mcd(a,b):
    assert type(a) == int and type(b) == int and a>0 and b>0
    if a%b != 0:
        return mcd(b,a%b)
    else:
        return b
```

Luego haces algo así como `numerador=numerador/mcd(numerador,denominador)` y `denominador=denominador/mcd(numerador,denominador)` y lo imprimes como string:

```
print(str(numerador)+'/'+str(denominador)).
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando la clase `Fraction` del módulo `fractions` no se retorna el valor de la fracción cuando esta tiene infinitos números decimales, por lo tanto es necesario agregar `.limit_denominator()` después de emplear la clase.

```py
from fractions import Fraction
a = 2/9
b=Fraction(str(a))
print('Valor de b: ',b)

c=Fraction(str(a)).limit_denominator()
print('Valor de c: ',c)
```

Y como resultado:

```py
Valor de b:  1111111111111111/5000000000000000
Valor de c:  2/9
```